# nsmutabledictionary is showing memory leak

Tags: iphone, memory-management

Why doing assigning nil to nsmutabledictioanry and allocating is crashing ans showing memory release at this point of place??

```
    self.delegate.replenishAddedmaterials = nil;
    self.delegate.replenishAddedmaterials = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    MATERIAL_ITEM *materialItem = [[MATERIAL_ITEM alloc] init];
    VENDOR_HEADER *vendor = [[VENDOR_HEADER alloc] init];
    PURCHASING_ORG_HEADER *purOrg = [[PURCHASING_ORG_HEADER alloc] init];

    [self.delegate.replenishAddedmaterials setObject:[NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:materialItem] forKey:materialItem];
    [[self.delegate.replenishAddedmaterials objectForKey:materialItem] addObject:vendor];
    [[self.delegate.replenishAddedmaterials objectForKey:materialItem] addObject:purOrg];
```

After executing allocation of nsmutabledictionary i am getting following message

*** -[MATERIAL_ITEM release]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x11e62810>I have implemented my project in ARC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure this line is correct?

```
     [self.delegate.replenishAddedmaterials setObject:[NSMutableArray 
arrayWithObject:materialItem] forKey:materialItem];
```

You are using the object on the array as the key, it's really weird.

Try creating a key yourself:

```
     [self.delegate.replenishAddedmaterials setObject:[NSMutableArray 
arrayWithObject:materialItem] forKey:@"materialItemKey"];
```

Comment: Actually i have object materialItem and it is unique,so for different material items having an array of objects for each materialitem key is the concept of creating dictionary like this.This is dynamic i will get key and values from server and programatically it is dynamic construction of dictionary.

Comment: if there is any other way where we can construct dictionaries

Comment: Just use a string as a key, like I said